# VLFeat - How to fix "Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory"?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vlfeat

I downloaded the [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/download.html) lib from its `git` repository! I followed the instruction in the [installation](http://www.vlfeat.org/download.html) page. But when I ran the `vl_setup` command I got this warning:

`Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: ..\Adv. 3D
Computer Vision\vlfeat\toolbox\mex\mexw32`

So follow some steps mentioned in MathWorks website, like [1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42690-warning-name-is-nonexistent-or-not-a-directory),[2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/245866),[3](http://itsallmacademic.com/2012/06/16/matlab-warning-name-is-nonexistent-or-not-a-directory/) but the problem didn't solve. I trace the `vl_setup.m` file and according to the error statement it can not find the `mexw32` folder. but there wasn't any folder like that when I downloaded that lib.

I'm using Windows 7, Matlab 2013a

Comment: I started bounty and I'm running it on linux.

Comment: @ytrewq You tried the [binary download](http://www.vlfeat.org/download.html), unpacked and run `toolbox/vl_setup`?

Comment: @ytrewq please provide all of the details of how you're setting up VLFeat and where things are going wrong.  I honestly think you should have just opened up a new question and didn't start a bounty.  Your issue may be different than the one that is described in this question.

Comment: @ytrewq did you also consult the compilation instructions for Mac OS / Linux? http://www.vlfeat.org/compiling-unix.html

Comment: @ytrewq The accepted answer worked for me! open a new question if it is different than what was asked!

Comment: @rayryeng I did make as in the general instruction, and run('VLFEATROOT/toolbox/vl_setup'), and the symptom is exactly the same as the original question, except I'm running it on ubuntu..

Comment: @rayryeng I have a feeling that your answer might work for me as well, except I need specific details on "compiling the mex files first through vl_compile.m"

Comment: @rayryeng thanx and waiting! :)

Comment: @rayryeng still eagerly waiting :(

Comment: @ytrewq It's prudent if you ask a new question.  I don't think it's correct that I edit this when the OP's issue is for Windows and your's is for Linux.  I don't think it was wise for you to start a bounty for an issue that is different.  In any case, go here: http://vision.princeton.edu/pvt/SiftFu/SiftFu/SIFTransac/vlfeat/doc/compiling.html.  You will also need to set up MEX to compile C or C++ files that were written to interface with MATLAB and you need to use `mex -setup` in the MATLAB command prompt. Choose the right compiler, then try and compile the toolbox again.

Comment: @rayryeng thanx! I actually started as a new question, but was flagged referring to this post as a duplicate..

Comment: @ytrewq Why do you insist on compiling when there is a pre-compiled version. Try that first, it avoids the complication of setting up the mex build tools. Then, if you are unhappy with that solution, you can first search posts about setting up mex on linux, and then open a new question if still unsuccessful. Always the easy thing first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you **compile** the `mex` files first through `vl_compile.m`?  Once you compile the code, the `mex` directory should appear with the `MEX` files associated with your OS.  Those setup instructions assume you have the **binary** distribution but you downloaded the source from `github`.

Consult VLFeat's compilation instructions for Windows here:  http://www.vlfeat.org/compiling-windows.html